# ui-router conditional reload on search

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, router

I have a route that I want to change when the path changes, but not when the search params change:

```
{
    name: 'single'
    url: '/{eID:[0-9]+}?action'
    controller: 'EventSingleCtrl as Event'
    templateProvider: ['$templateCache', ($templateCache) ->
        return $templateCache.get('views/events/single/Template.html')
    ],
    reloadOnSearch: false
}
```

In this case, a change in `eID` should reload the URL

I don't know how to detect when a state change occurs (because `reloadOnSearch` is set). Even if I try to debug by:

Loading an initial view => load same view with diffeent `eID` => `$state.$current.params.eID` still shows the old value

Comment: Are you using 0.2.15?

Comment: 0.2.13 - Are there any significant changes in .15 that can help this case?

Comment: yes, 0.2.15 fixed some reloadOnSearch stuff